# sliver light application deploy on Linux

Tags: linux, silverlight

My requirement is host a silver light web site on Linux O/S on tomcat or web logic server.
would appreciate if anyone can explain the possibility and approach for this.

Regards,
vidya

Comment: Isn't Silverlight a client side technology? You just put the files somewhere under the server root.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight):

### Moonlight

> **Moonlight** is an open source
>   implementation of Silverlight
>   (http://silverlight.net), primarily
>   for Linux and other Unix/X11 based
>   operating systems. In September of
>   2007, Microsoft and Novell announced a
>   technical collaboration that includes
>   access to Microsoft's test suites for
>   Silverlight and the distribution of a
>   Media Pack for Linux users that will
>   contain licensed media codecs for
>   video and audio.
>
> Moonlight 2 was released December 17,
>   2009

---

I am certain Moonlight will NOT work as a drop in replacement and am not sure it will come cheaper than using a vanilla Microsoft/Windows based system, since that depends on the 'cost of time', 'cost of risk'.

### COST (guestimate)

```
Silverlight           vs.     Moonlight
-----------                  ----------
license                      - 
install/config               install/config time
-                            compatibility risk
HW                           HW
```